# Painting the background of a QTableView (with a custom QStyledItemDelegate)

Tags: c++, qt

I've been trying to use a "per-cell" custom background in a (custom) `QTableView` using a (custom) `QStyledItemDelegate`. Everything works well, until I actually try to have my custom background. Let's say for the sake of example, I want all my cells to have a red background. Here's the `paint` method of my  `Delegate`.

```cpp
    QStyleOptionViewItem newOption = option;
    auto normalText = newOption.palette.brush(QPalette::ColorGroup::Normal, QPalette::ColorRole::Text);
    // Works as expected
    newOption.palette.setBrush(QPalette::ColorGroup::Normal, QPalette::ColorRole::Highlight, Qt::gray); // QBrush(Qt::GlobalColor::blue, Qt::BrushStyle::NoBrush));
    // Expected too: selected cells are gray
    newOption.palette.setBrush(QPalette::ColorGroup::Normal, QPalette::ColorRole::HighlightedText, normalText);

    // All of the following do NOT work. I've tried every possible combination without success.
    newOption.palette.setBrush(QPalette::ColorGroup::Normal, QPalette::ColorRole::Window, Qt::red);
    newOption.palette.setBrush(QPalette::ColorGroup::Inactive, QPalette::ColorRole::Base, Qt::red);
    newOption.palette.setBrush(QPalette::ColorGroup::Inactive, QPalette::ColorRole::AlternateBase, Qt::red);
    newOption.palette.setBrush(QPalette::ColorGroup::Active, QPalette::ColorRole::Base, Qt::red);
    newOption.palette.setBrush(QPalette::ColorGroup::Active, QPalette::ColorRole::AlternateBase, Qt::red);
    QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, newOption, index);
```

How am I supposed to achieve that? I thought my way of doing it was rather simple  and intuitive... What's wrong here?

Comment: The easier approach is handling `Qt::BackgroundRole` role in your table's model.

Comment: I've got two issues with using `data` and `BackgroundRole`. The first one is that using it implies that the background color of the cell is some kind of *data* from the model, which it is not. Also, I will later want to have a custom border drawing for certain cells, and I won't be able to do this in `data` by using `BackgroundRole` as you suggest. That's why I'd rather keep all of this here, in the `delegate`'s `paint`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has the following errors:

- Do not use the [`paint()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html#paint) method if you want to customize the properties of the [`QStyleOptionViewItem`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleoptionviewitem.html) since within the [`paint()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html#paint) method it will be overwritten by the [`initStyleOption()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html#initStyleOption) method that is called internally.
- Not all the properties of the painting are obtained from [`QPalette`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpalette.html), in the case of the background color you must use the [`backgroundBrush`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleoptionviewitem.html#backgroundBrush-var) property.

Considering the above the solution is:

```cpp
#include <QtWidgets>

class StyledItemDelegate: public QStyledItemDelegate
{
public:
    using QStyledItemDelegate::QStyledItemDelegate;
protected:
    void initStyleOption(QStyleOptionViewItem *option, const QModelIndex &index) const override
    {
        QStyledItemDelegate::initStyleOption(option, index);
        QBrush normalText = option->palette.brush(QPalette::ColorGroup::Normal, QPalette::ColorRole::Text);
        option->palette.setBrush(QPalette::ColorGroup::Normal, QPalette::ColorRole::Highlight, Qt::gray);
        option->palette.setBrush(QPalette::ColorGroup::Normal, QPalette::ColorRole::HighlightedText, normalText);
        option->backgroundBrush = QColor(Qt::red);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QTableView w;
    StyledItemDelegate *delegate = new StyledItemDelegate(&w);
    w.setItemDelegate(delegate);
    QStandardItemModel model(10, 10);
    w.setModel(&model);
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's troublesome, but if you step through the source of `QStyledItemDelegate::paint()`, deep down inside you'll find some hard-coded values there (e.g. background color of selected items).

I ended up drawing *over* instead of *under* the `QStyledItemDelegate::paint()` with a semi-transparent painter / brush / image (after the base class call).

If the selection behavior isn't important to you, try performing the painting yourself **before** calling `QStyledItemDelegate::paint()` and see if that suits your needs.

Comment: You mean by first calling `QStyledItemDelegate::paint` and only after calling whatever I need to do? What I don't like is that I'll have to actually draw things myself, and I fear that would be best done if Qt did it itself. Isn't there another way?